# How to select another type of font with QFont?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfont

I am trying to assign different types of text fonts to my application with PyQt5, but I don't know how to assign a different one to the standard one, for example in my application I could only assign it 'Roboto', but if I want to change to Roboto-MediumItalic, I don't know how to specify that font type to it, i'm newbie to python and pyqt5

```
QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Static/fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf")
label2.setFont(QFont('Roboto',12))
```

folders

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the styles and QFontDatabase to use `Roboto-MediumItalic`. You can also set the italic weight style through QFont.

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDir
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def load_fonts_from_dir(directory):
    families = set()
    for fi in QDir(directory).entryInfoList(["*.ttf"]):
        _id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(fi.absoluteFilePath())
        families |= set(QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(_id))
    return families


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    font_dir = CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "Static" / "fonts"
    families = load_fonts_from_dir(os.fspath(font_dir))
    print(families)

    db = QFontDatabase()
    styles = db.styles("Roboto")
    print(styles)

    font = db.font("Roboto", "Medium Italic", 12)

    # OR
    # font = QFont("Roboto", pointSize=12, weight=QFont.Medium, italic=True)

    label = QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.setFont(font)
    label.setText("Hello world!!")
    label.resize(640, 480)
    label.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```